# It necessary to stop bitcoind when I shutdown Linux server? It will stop safely by it own?

Tags: bitcoind, linux

I run bitcoind on mini pc using Debian as headless server -auto run by cron and without connect monitor-. Normally when I want shutdown, I do "bitcoin-cli stop" then "shutdown now".

Question is: Does is necessary to do "bitcoin-cli stop"? Or I can safely "shutdown now" then it will close bitcoind automatic?